# Do you know of anyway to get a distinct result set without using the ResultTransformer when using SetFirstResult and SetMaxResults?

Tags: .net, nhibernate, criteria, distinct

When i use SetFirstResult and SetMaxResult and if the query has joins the result have duplicate results instead of unique.

Then i use all type of Distinct helpers for criteria api. But it doesnt filter the whole result set it just filters the paged result.

How can i overcome this issue ?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have found a [hacky thing to overcome](http://opensource.atlassian.com/projects/hibernate/browse/HB-520) this issue.

> The only "workaround" for this that
>   I've been able to come up with is to
>   issue two queries from the criteria
>   same criteria object. The first one
>   gets the id's the second one is
>   contrained to the ids.
>
> //set up crtieria as you wish,
>   including pagination myCriteria =
>   doStuffToSetupCriteria();
>   myCriteria.setFirstResult((page-1)*itemsPerPage);
>   myCriteria.setMaxResults(itemsPerPage);
>
> //get the list if primary keys
>   myCriteria.setProjection(Projections.distinct(Projections.property("myAllias.id"));
>   List ids = gacc.list();
>
> //now add the id's into the
>   restriction 
>   myCriteria.add(Restrictions.in("myAlias.id,
>   ids));
>
> //clean up from the last critiera run
>   gacc.setProjection(null);
>   gacc.setFirstResult(0);
>   gacc.setMaxResults(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
>
> //your results List objects =
>   gacc.list()
>
> A little hacky I agree, but the only
>   acceptable soltion I could find given
>   this limitiation.

Comment: ResultTransformer filters results on the client, but Projections.Distinct should issue a "distinct" keyword on the query. Doesn't that work?

Comment: Does "on the client" mean that, it gets all the stuff from DB and filter it on the ram instead of on sql server ?

Comment: ohh,it is really dangerous to use. Projections.Distinct is the winner then :)

Answer (score 1):

I built a similiar solution but in just one trip to DB:

DetachedCriteria subQuery = ...//-->Add all Criterions you want and inclusive "SetFirstResult" and "SetMaxResults"

DetachedCriteria rootQuery = DetachedCriteria.For(); // where T is an entity

subQuery.SetProjection(
    **Projections.Distinct(
       Projections.ProjectionList().Add(Projections.Alias(Projections.Property("ID"), "ID"))
                        )**
                      );

// Note: all my entities inherit from a base class who contains a property "ID"
rootQuery.Add(Subqueries.PropertyIn("ID", subQuery));

// ...then use rootQuery to get the List of T and no repeated item will be retrieved.

I hope someone find this implementation helpfull :)

Román